# Moving elements between two std::vectors without making copies

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, std, move-semantics

Say I have two vectors:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SomeObject>> some_vector
```

and

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SomeObject>> filtered_vector
```

If I need to **very frequently move elements between these two vectors**, how can I do so **without making any copies**?

I know **move semantics** is a possible option, and I'm going in this direction but I just wanted to see what the best way of achieving this would be.